# How to put 'and' condition to remove an xml element from an xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT and got a condition to remove an element from XML file on the basis of condition applied in XSLT. I have to remove en element on the basis of 2 conditions on the same attribute.

Here is my dummy code:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="cdm:attributeList/cdm:attribute[cdm:attributeName = 'format'] and cdm:attributeList/cdm:attribute[cdm:attributeValue = 'XYZ']" />
```

while running the XSLT file I get the following error:
1. Extra illegal tokens: 'and'
2.  "exclude-result-prefixes" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:output element!

Could someone please help me out in this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the input XML where you running the code?

Answer (score 0):

The template matching condition is incorrect, `and` operator is not allowed when matching template. You need to modify the template matching condition as below which corresponds to the combination of the required conditions.

```
<xsl:template match="cdm:attributeList/cdm:attribute[cdm:attributeName = 'format'][cdm:attributeValue = 'XYZ']" />
```

For the second issue of `exclude-result-prefixes`, it is an attribute of `<xsl:stylesheet>` and not `<xsl:output>`. So if you do not want the output nodes to have the `cdm` prefix, modify the `<xsl:stylesheet>` as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:cdm="http://someurl" exclude-result-prefixes="cdm">
```